# Get the value of a html text box in office share point

Tags: sharepoint-2013

How to get the HTML text box value to show alert message in office share point.

```
function show(){
     alert('test:' +  $("#txtPrice").val());
}
```

After I have deployed the project from visual studio (successful deploy) and I go to my office share point site the alert is not showed. How can I get the text box value?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you Call your show function?

Have you load jQuery library?

You'd better provide more details for your solution.

Update:

The code is fine, make sure the jQuery library is loaded correctly and try to add your site to trust site to check whether you disable JavaScript for your browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show() {
            alert('test:' + $("#txtPrice").val());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="txtPrice" type="text" /> 
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="show();" id="btnCreate" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image][image]

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: <input id="txtPrice" type="text" />     <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="show();" id="btnCreate"  />  for me  the alert function shows empty but can't show the text box value. i want to show textbox value in alert function.